im getting the error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch while trying to post to bloger from python
I want to post on blogger with python with blogger api but i cant, i spent 24 hours and still cant make it work, this is the code
import os
import google.auth
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

# Ruta al archivo de credenciales OAuth 2.0 que descargaste
CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'cred.json'

# ID del blog donde vas a publicar (lo puedes encontrar en la URL de tu blog en Blogger)
BLOG_ID = '2045983628813599998'

def authenticate_blogger_api():
    """Autentica y crea un cliente de la API de Blogger"""
    # Definir los alcances que vamos a usar (escribir y leer entradas)
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger']

    # Carga de credenciales desde el archivo
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)

    # Ejecuta el flujo de OAuth 2.0 para autenticar al usuario
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    # Crear un cliente de la API de Blogger
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('blogger', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    return service

def create_blog_post(service, blog_id, title, content):
    """Crea una nueva entrada en Blogger"""
    # Crear el cuerpo de la nueva entrada
    post = {
        'kind': 'blogger#post',
        'title': title,
        'content': content
    }

    # Usar la API para insertar la entrada en el blog
    try:
        posts = service.posts()
        result = posts.insert(blogId=blog_id, body=post).execute()
        print(f"Entrada publicada con éxito: {result['url']}")
    except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as error:
        print(f"Ocurrió un error: {error}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Autenticación a la API de Blogger
    service = authenticate_blogger_api()

    # Título y contenido de la nueva entrada
    title = "Mi primera entrada desde Python"
    content = "<h1>Hola Mundo desde Python</h1><p>Este es un post creado automáticamente usando la API de Blogger.</p>"

    # Crear la entrada en el blog
    create_blog_post(service, BLOG_ID, title, content)


but it doesnt work, it sends me to my browser and says
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
denied acces, what am i doing wrong?
these are some of the credentials from the json

    "redirect_uris": ["https://localhost:8080/"]
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
i put 2 google acounts in the oauth proyect but it doesnt work


i tried to add and remove more accounts but it doesnt work

It's probably "redirect_uri_mismatch" error. This happens when the redirect URI in your  credentials doesn’t match what’s expected in the flow. After you authenticate, Google tries to redirect you, but if the URI doesn’t match, it gives you a 400 error, blocking the process.
Check this here
oAuth returning 400 bad request
